# How to stop the beep after I handle the WM_SYSKEYDOWN message?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, message

I want my control do something when I press Alt+Enter key combination. I achieve this by catching the `WM_SYSKEYDOWN`. But everytime a "syskey" combination is pressed the system makes a beep and I don't know how to stop it. I tried to return 0 (`Message.Result:=0`), clear the char code (`Message.CharCode:=0`) or not calling the inherited method but with no success. I found that this beep is not made in my `WMSysKeyDown` procedure, but after it.

In my real control I don't have a TEdit, but that doesn't matter, the beep is made in every control.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TMyControl = class(TEdit)
  private
    procedure WMSysKeyDown(var Message: TWMSysKeyDown); message WM_SYSKEYDOWN;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    MyControl:TMyControl;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TMyControl.WMSysKeyDown(var Message: TWMKey);
begin
 case Message.CharCode of
  VK_RETURN: if (Message.KeyData and $40000000)=0 then begin
    TForm(Parent).Caption:=TForm(Parent).Caption+' x';
    Message.Result:=0;
  end;
 end;
 inherited;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 MyControl:=TMyControl.Create(Form1);
 MyControl.Parent:=Form1;
end;

end.
```

Comment: @TLama, `WM_SYSCHAR` it is ! :) I removed the `CharCode` (assigned #0) and is not beeping anymore. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Use PeekMessage function. (Winapi function). Delete all message on the queue. I guess you will find detailed instruction in winapi peekmessage help.

```
procedure TMyControl.WMSysKeyDown(var Message: TWMKey);
var
  Mesaj : TMsg ;
begin
 case Message.CharCode of
  VK_RETURN:
    if (Message.KeyData and $40000000)=0 then
    begin
      TForm(Parent).Caption:=TForm(Parent).Caption+' x';
      PeekMessage(Mesaj, Form1.Handle, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE); // Here is the answer. Delete all queued messages in the message queue
    end;
  end;
 inherited;
end;
```

Comment: Indeed, it's working... but how can I delete all the messages in the queue ?? Maybe there are important messages...

Comment: It is not delete all messages. Delete Only one message in the message queue. I think I explained wrong (sorry my english :)  It deletes only one message when user press RETURN key. I wish I explained correctly now.

Comment: Sorry my english. It deletes One message here is the delete All messages explanation. I wrote Delete ONE Message :)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644928(v=vs.85).aspx#examining_queue (ooops I am new on stack overflow user interface. I make mistakes when I am writing :)

Comment: PeekMessage(Mesaj, Form1.Handle, WM_KEYFIRST, WM_KEYLAST, PM_REMOVE) please try this. Deletes only KEYboard messages. It doesnt touch other messages.

Comment: Yes, Adnan, but it's better with `PeekMessage(Mesaj, Handle, WM_SYSCHAR, WM_SYSCHAR, PM_REMOVE)` because that is the message that beeps. I gave you +1 because you showed me this very usefull function `PeekMessage`, that I was not aware.

Comment: PeekMessage? Not what's needed here at all.

Comment: @Marus, it's not a good idea to touch the message queue. I would just handle the `WM_SYSCHAR` message and do not call `inherited` to eat the keystroke (which will stop that beeping).